# Unsure about three simple functions with C programming

Tags: c

```
/* stringlength
 * input: str, pointer to a string
 * output: integer representing the length of string str, 
 * not counting the terminating character.
 *
 * You may NOT call ANY functions within this function.
 */
int stringlength(char *str)
{
    // count the number of characters in str
  int count=0,k;
  for (k=0; str[k] != '\0';k++)
    count++;
    return count;
}

/* countchars
 * inputs: character c, string str
 * output:  The number of instances of c in the string str
 * You may not call ANY function calls within this function.
 */
int countchars(char c, char *str)
{
    // count the number of times c is found in str
  int k,count=0;
  for (k=0;str[k]=='\0';k++)
    {
      if (str[k] == c)
    count++;
      else;
    }

    return count;
}

/* countlines
 * input: char *filename - string containing the filename
 * output: integer representing the number of lines in the file
 */
int countlines(char *filename)
{
    // count the number of lines in the file called filename
  FILE *f = fopen(filename,"r");
    char ch;
    int lines=0;
  f = fopen(filename,"r");

  do{
    ch = fgetc(f);
    if( ch == '\n')
      lines++;
  }while( ch != EOF );

return lines;
}
```

I need help with these three different functions that I am implementing in my program. I am a beginner so go easy on me, the countlines function is giving me the most trouble. If anyone could explain why not or why these functions will work, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The homework tag is deprecated. Please don't use it.

Comment: What doesn't work with these functions?

Comment: Code works now, minor fixes. Thank you @Jonathon Leffler

Comment: @chris I missed the deprecation of the "homework" tag (which seems a sensible tag here). Any text somewhere explaining that?

Comment: @bortzmeyer, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems in `countlines()`:

1. You open the file twice, but overwrite the first `FILE *` value with the second, so there's no way you can close it.  This is a minor problem.
2. The major problem is that the function `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  In particular, `EOF` is a value different from every `char`.
3. The code does not close the file before returning.  Generally, if you open a file in a function, then you should close it.  If you don't, you have to pass the file pointer back to the calling code so that it can close it.
4. The `do ... while` loop is seldom correct for an input loop (a `while` loop testing at the top is almost always much cleaner and clearer) but at least you weren't using `feof()`.

   ```
   int countlines(char *filename)
   {
       FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
       int ch;
       int lines = 0;
       if (fp == 0)
           return lines;

       while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
       {
           if (ch == '\n')
               lines++;
       }

       fclose(fp);

       return lines;
   }
   ```

When you use `char` instead, one of two things happens:

- If your `char` type is `signed`, then a real character (often ÿ — y-umlaut, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) also matches `EOF` so you can stop reading before you reach end of file.
- If your `char` type is `unsigned`, no value will ever match `EOF` so the loop will never stop.

---

In `stringlength()`, you have two variables `count` and `k` that are carefully kept at the same value; you only need one of the two.

---

Apart from raggedy indentation (endemic in the code shown — and definitely something to be avoided), and the unnecessary and pointless `else;` which does absolutely nothing, the code for `countchars()` <s>looks OK</s> (*late addition*) ... has the condition in the `for` loop inverted; it should be `str[k] != '\0'`, of course.

Comment: `EOF` being in the range [`CHAR_MIN`,-1] (when `char` is signed) is truly awkward, although restricting file/printable `chars` to ASCII lets the standard and implementations get away with it.

Comment: my countchars() function does not work, I believe my for loop was written incorrectly. I am trying to fix the other two as well.

Comment: @Michael_19 What does your call to countchars() look like?

Comment: changing my for loop fixed the issue.

Comment: @Michael_19 How exactly did you change it? `str[k] != '\0'` like that?

Comment: for (k=0;str[k]!='\0';k++) //what i changed it to, did the trick