# How can I count the occurrences of a character in a file?

Tags: c, file

The function is called as so,

```
printf("%d occurrences of %c in %s\n",
        countoccurrences(argv[1], argv[1][0]),
            argv[1][0], argv[1]);
```

and this is my function so far:

```
    /* countcharinfile
     * input: char *filename, char c
     * output: the number of occurrences of char c inside file filename
     */
int countoccurrences(char *filename, char c)
{
        // count the number of occurrences of c in the file named filename      
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
  int ch,count=0;
  while ((ch = fgetc(fp) != EOF))
    {

      if (ch == c)
        count++;
    }

        return count;
}
```

When I run the program, `./main Today is a beutiful day`

I get the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Please copy/paste the exact error message (I'm assuming that isn't the exact error message).

Comment: main.c:168:5: error: conflicting types for ‘countoccurrences’
main.c:169:1: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
main.c:69:3: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘countoccurrences’ was here

Comment: Not related, but you are not initializing count

Comment: You didn't make sure there was a full prototype declaration of your function `countoccurrences()` visible before you used the function.  The compiler is kind and letting you know about the issue.

Comment: Idiomatic C would use `while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { if (ch == c) count++; }` for the loop.  Avoid the `do ... while` loop most of the time.  That part of your code is OK; it will work correctly.  But it isn't the way most C programmers would write it, and it would be easy for it not to work OK.

Comment: Okay, I changed my code a bit and added the function declaration before my main. Now when I run the program I get a new error.

Comment: Your program crashes because it failed to open the file `Today` and you forgot to check that the `fopen()` call succeeded.  See my answer to your question y'day ([Unsure about three simple functions with C programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658820/unsure-about-three-simple-functions-with-c-programming)).

Comment: @Michael_19, as mentioned in my answer you need to check return value of `fopen()`. Is there a file named `"Today"` in the same directory as `main` ?

Comment: No. I would like it to take the argv[1] which is today and the argv[1][0] which is 'T' and print how many times that character occured in argv[1].

Comment: @Michael_19, you want to examine a string, not a file then. If `argv[1]` is `"today"` then `argv[1][0]` is `t`, not `T`.

Comment: Writing `if ((...))` is always either wrong or pointlessly excessive ... usually the former ... `ch` will always have a value of `1`.

Comment: You've edited the code, invalidating responses ... that's a no-no.

Comment: When you copied the code from my comment, you mis-parenthesized the condition in the `while`; look at where the parentheses are in your code, vs in the code in my comment.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using your function `countoccurrences` in `main` before it's been defined.

Add a function signature before `main`:

```
int countoccurrences(char *, char);
```

Or move the function itself to a place in your code before your `main` function.

Also:

- you need to initialize your `count` variable to zero in `countoccurences`, and
- you should check that `fp != NULL` before you use the file pointer. `fopen` will return NULL if it can't open the file.

> When I run the program, ./main Today is a beutiful day

When you run your program this way, you are passing it 5 arguments, one for each word in your sentence. Review your function and your function call in `main`: the function wants a *file name* to search, which should be the first argument to your program, not the text to search. And the second argument should be the character to search for.

Since you're not checking the return value of `fopen`, your invocation here will cause problems, because you probably *don't* have a file named *Today* in the working directory.

Comment: @Michael_19 please edit the question and add your function signature.

Comment: I added the function declaration to the program, that was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that the function declaration or definition was not visible at the point where it is called. Move the definition or put a declaration prior to `main()`.

Other points:

- Check return value of `fopen()`
- Initialise `count`
- `buf` is an unused local variable

For example:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
if (fp)
{
    int ch,count=0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (ch == c) count++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr,
            "Failed to open %s: %s\n",
            filename,
            strerror(errno));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C needs to know about your function signature before the call. Either:

1. Move your function before the call, or
2. Put a declaration before the call (at the global scope of course)

   `int countoccurrences(char *filename, char c);`

You also need to initialize count (presumably to 0). You should make sure you are calling it with the right value. If you want to use the first character of the second parameter you should use `argv[2][0]`.